# Modifying Windows Ctrl+Del behavior across different programs

Tags: python, windows-7, textbox, autohotkey, ctrl

I would like to override the behavior of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> in various programs in Windows 7 which do not delete whole words before or after caret by default. Eg: Notepad displays a box looking character (not sure which one) when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

Is there a fix for this in Windows 7?

Could i use Python, Autohotkey, or anoother language to override this behavour? Eg: find the position of the cursor/caret and delete the following whole word.

Comment: Notepad isn't intended for serious work. Hence it being called **NOTE**pad. Microsoft hasn't really updated that app AT ALL except for perhaps adding unicode support.

Comment: You can tell because they haven't even added a ribbon UI to it :P

Answer (score 1):

AutoHotkey will do what you want.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad
^Delete::SendInput something else
#IfWinActive
```

You can find the ahk_class with Au3 Window Spy, and a list of keys in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

> delete whole words before or after caret

```
^Del::SendInput ^+{Right}{Delete}

^BackSpace::SendInput ^+{Left}{Delete}
```

This relies on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> selecting the word to the left of the caret, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> selecting the word to the right of the caret.

---

If you only want to enable it for specific programs, you can follow the suggestions of the other answers, for example using [`#IfWinActive`](http://autohotkey.net/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) coupled with `ahk_class`, like so:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad
^Del::SendInput ^+{Right}{Delete}    
^BackSpace::SendInput ^+{Left}{Delete}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will give you a start...

```
^Del::
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
IfWinActive, Application title ; Use windows spy
{
    Send, xyz ; modified behaviour
}
Else
{
    Send, ^{Del} ; Original behaviour
}
Return
```